# How to record error message in a new column of my data frame?

Tags: r

I have a `R` Script that contains around 100 "jobs" of scraping data and saving the results in several Excel files. This R Script runs fine when I hit `Ctrl + Enter` in `RStudio`.

However, since the data is located on an html table on a webpage, the script will throw the following error message in cases where the html table is not present: `Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

This error does not stop the script in its execution. It will continue to the next line of code.

And here is the set of R codes that will throw this error:

```
output3 <- url3 %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = './/table[@id="hprt-table"]')  %>%
   html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

Is it possible to "catch" this error and insert it in a new column of my data frame?

Therefore, that new column would autofill all rows with "subscript out of bounds". Else, it needs to autofill with "OK"

If I need to hardcode that piece, it would look something like this (the new column being called "Remarks"):

```
df1$Remarks <- 'subscript out of bounds'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Added (full R codes):

```
url3 <- read_html("https://www.xxxxx.com") 

output3 <- url3 %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = './/table[@id="hprt-table"]')  %>%
  html_table() %>% .[[1]]

hotelname <- url3%>%
  html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='hp_hotel_name']/span/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>%
  html_text(trim = T)

colnames(output3)[5] <- "Quantity"

#Clean up columns
#remove repeating information in 2 columns
output31 <- output3 %>% mutate_at(c("Room type", "Price for 5 nights"), ~str_extract(., ".*\n"))

#Remove repeating newlines
answer31<-output31 %>% mutate_all(str_squish)

df1<-answer31 %>% 
  mutate(Price = as.numeric(stringr::str_remove_all(`Price for 5 nights`, "\\D"))) %>%
  #mutate(OtherPrices = (stringr::str_extract_all(`Quantity`, "\\([^()]+\\)"))) %>%
  mutate(DiscountedPrice = as.numeric(gsub(',', '', sub('.*?\\(MUR (.*?)\\).*', '\\1',`Quantity`)))) %>%
  ungroup ()

#create a new column in df1 called StartDate
df$StartDate <- '2021-11-15'

#create a new column in df1 called EndDate
df$EndDate <- '2021-11-20'

#create a new column in df1 called Hotel and fill that column with the Hotel Name
df1$Hotel <- hotelname
  
#create a new column in df1 called CaptureDate and fill that column with the date of data capture
df1$CaptureDate <- Sys.Date()

#output is saved as an Excel Workbook with a time stamp
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df1), 
           file = paste0('rt_df1-', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'), 
           sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: What is `df1` ? Is this code running in some kind of `for` loop? Can you show the loop code?

Comment: df1 is the final data frame name. No there is no loop. It is just a set of codes which saves df1 as an Excel file.

Comment: write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df1), 
           file = paste0('rt_df1-', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'), 
           sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)

Comment: I have added the full set of R codes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take help of `if`/`else` in the script to check the output

```
output3 <- url3 %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = './/table[@id="hprt-table"]')  %>%
  html_table()

if(NROW(output3) > 0) {
  output3 <- output3 %>% .[[1]]
  
  hotelname <- url3%>%
    html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='hp_hotel_name']/span/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>%
    html_text(trim = T)
  #...
  #...
  #...
  
  df1$CaptureDate <- Sys.Date()

} else {
  df1 <- data.frame(Remarks = 'subscript out of bounds')
}

write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df1), 
           file = paste0('rt_df1-', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'), 
           sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. what do I insert in #... ?

Comment: That is all the code that you want to apply when a dataframe is present. Sorry, if that was not clear. Maybe the edit is helpful.

Comment: Thanks but still not working. I get the following error message: "Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Quantity")) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions". 

It does write the data frame to an Excel file but no new column is created.